# Adding custom SDK based on Andorid version 11 to Android studio

Tags: android, sdk, build.gradle, android-sdk-tools, android-11

[Error showing in build.gradle file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9WI3.png)
Android Version - 11
Android Studio - Giraffe

- I am trying to create a custom SDK which contains API developed by me. I want to access these API's in Android Studio.
- I found out that there are two ways to do it

1. Android SDK-Addon
2. Android Custom SDK
   I am trying the 2nd way.

How i created Custom SDK:

- I have aosp source code for Android 11 and I Have added a Custom System Service in frameworks/base folder and made it to start when system server starts. (FYI: I am aware of the consequences if i add system services in frameworks, It's just for learning purpose).
  *[I used this blog as a reference](https://saurabhsharma123k.blogspot.com/2020/02/androidaosp-system-service-in-details.html)
- I even accessed the API in application using getSystemService("API_MANAGER_NAME").
- To access the same API in Android Studio I created a custom SDK from my AOSP.
- [To build custom SDK i followed Google documentation](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/sdk/+/master/docs/howto_build_SDK.txt)- lunch my_menu and make sdk
- After this i could able to see Android SDK in /out/host/linux-x86/sdk/. I verified in the platform/android.jar and it contains my API stub class.
- I gave the path of my custom Android SDK in Android Studio and extracted the contents.

PROBLEM:

- The API i built is for 30( Android 11) but in Android Studio Gradle file Application is set to target and compile for API version 34 (Android 13).
- If I try to access my API with this changes i cannot able to see my API and import will also fail.
- I tried to change the compile and target sdk version to 30 and i found that this error (Screenshot)
- With the degraded versions of API 30, I could able to import my API but the dependencies associated in gradle file will fail. It targets for API version 33 only.
- I want to have an application which is targeting for API 30 ( compile, min, and target all pointing to same API level which is 30 ) and dependency present in gradle file to be compatible with this changes. So that i can import my custom API without resulting in Automotive debug resource fail error.
- I tried changing the API versions in gradle and it resulted in error of the library present in gradle file.

Comment: Is this modified SDK just for you or is it distributed to other people? If it only for you, adding your API as gradle dependecy marked as `compileOnly` would be easier.

Comment: No Robert, I am thinking to distribute to others. Also what do you mean by compileOnly for my API. Because i am not trying to add it as dependency in gradle as ajar file. Instead my API is included in the SDK. I am just trying to import it and call the API.

Comment: I was talking about using the regular SDK and just providing your extended API as library. That library could then be integrated into Gradle using `compileOnly` dependency type. So there would be no need to modify the SDK.

Comment: Yea I know that way i.e SDK Addon but I want to try building a new custom SDK rather than using the existing SDK.